# Pass a file descriptor from parent to child in Perl

Tags: perl, fork, ipc, file-descriptor

I'm writing a multiplayer networked game in Perl with the following architecture:

The parent waits for connections and after each six connections, forks a child to handle those connections. Each child then runs its own game.

The problem is that if a client on one of those child processes disconnects I do not have a good way to reconnect him. I have set up a pipe between the parent and each child and when a client reconnects I send the file descriptor through the pipe to the clients. The client is supposed to reconnect the client from that file descriptor.

The problem is that the file descriptors do not seem to be openable by the child processes even though the sockets are working fine in the parent. When the client attempts to reopen a socket using the `new_from_fd()` call, I do not get an error, but when I send to the socket I get a "send: Cannot determine peer address" error.

Is there a way to get around this? I can provide code snippets if necessary, but I feel as if this is a logical design issue.

Comment: Sample code or an illustrative example would probably help. I'd suggest the problem is that the socket will be closing when the process terminates, and 'reopening' it doesn't work so simply.

Comment: I'm not reopening the same socket. I'm sending the new socket file descriptor from parent to child and opening it from there.

Comment: There is only two portable ways you can send/pass file descriptors to another processes, by inheritance or by passing them through a unix domain socket. This is known as file descriptor passing. There are a couple of modules on CPAN related to this task, I have used [IO::FDPass](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::FDPass).